# Using ServiceStack JsonServiceClient with Angular Cli

Tags: angular, servicestack, angular-cli

I'm attempting to use the ServiceStack typescript client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/servicestack-client) @version 0.0.34
with an Angular 4.0 application generated with the angular cli version 1.0. 
When I run

`ng serve`

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in D:/dev/STASH/Meter/meters-web/src/meter-analytics/node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts (234,14): Cannot find name 'Headers'.
(path redacted)/node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts (240,26): Cannot find name 'Request'.
(path redacted)/node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts (241,27): Cannot find name 'Response'.
(path redacted)/node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts (242,28): Cannot find name 'Response'.
(path redacted)/node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts (266,21): Cannot find name 'Response'.
```

I have tried both trouble shooting tips for this issue recommended on the npm page for the servicestack-client to pull in the es2016 libs

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "lib": [
        "es2016"
      ]
   }
 }
```

or to pull in the fetch type defintions

`npm install @types/whatwg-fetch --save-dev`

but neither resolve the issue.

I was using the json service client @0.0.33 with angular 2.0 with a beta-19 of the angular cli without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are due to the missing Type definitions for W3C fetch library. Manually adding the type definitions from:

```
npm install @types/whatwg-fetch --save-dev
```

Should resolve the issue, otherwise if you upgrade to TypeScript later than **2.2+** the fetch Type definitions will be available when referencing the built-in **es2016** lib, e.g:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "lib": [
        "es2016"
      ]
   }
}
```

If you're getting these designer errors in VS.NET 2017, it's because it's still using an older v2.1 version of TypeScript that didn't include W3C fetch definitions in its built-in Type definitions. This will be resolved in the next version of VS2017 (or available now in the [current VS2017 preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/)) which will be able to use your local version of TypeScript. In the meantime you can prevent VS2017 TypeScript errors from blocking the build by editing your `.csproj` to include `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>`, e.g:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

If you're using `ng-serve` it should be using your local version of TypeScript so if you upgrade to TypeScript 2.2 or 2.3 you should no longer have this error.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded from typescript 2.2 to 2.3.2 and using the compiler options in my tsconfig resolved the issue.    Will you consider adding the peerDependencies section to the servicestack-client package to prevent this type of issue in the future?